# NodeJS db.end() Confusion

Tags: mysql, node.js

First and foremost, I'm using this module: https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql

The issue I have is I need to use `db.end()` inside each `db.query` function.

For example:

```
 db.query('SELECT query here ', function(err, results){
 //What if I want to run another query here after getting data? I do this:
  db.query('SELECT query here ', function(err, results){

});

db.end();
});
```

If I were to remove that `db.end();` at the end of the first query call, I would get these [image: sleep processes] that start piling up in my process listing window.

Which is totally understandable because I am not ending the connection. My confusion is, I do **NOT need** to add a `db.end()` below to my second query function... and even if I do not, it doesn't add sleep processes.. **why?** Does the outermost `db.end()` end all queries that are within its scope?

Comment: [Introduction](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql/#introduction): `[...]Closing the connection is done using end() which makes sure all remaining queries are executed before sending a quit packet to the mysql server.[...]`

Comment: @t.niese I see, hmm. what if an error were to occur inside the 2nd query call?

Comment: I'm not sure what you think that could happen then. The connection will still be closed as long as `db.end()` was called.

Comment: How will it still be closed though if there is no db.end() inside of the query function? Sorry but this is my first time with Asynchronous code.

Comment: Why do you think the `db.end()` would not be called? Because the execution of the code is async the 2nd query will happen after the `db.end()` is called. But event if it wont be async then `db.end()` will still be called because `.query` does not throw an exception when you provide a callback, but will pass the error as first param.

Comment: Yeah, as you said. The 2nd query will happen after `db.end` is called. If `db.end` is already called though, how can it work with whatever is in the 2nd query call? So basically the code is being run from the outside in? Everything outside of the most inner function will be applied to the inner inside code?

Comment: it is added to the queue before `end` is called, and because of my first comment the lib wont close the connection untill all active/queued queries are finished. `end` in this case is not like turning of the light immediately, but telling the light turn to off as soon as the room is empty.

Comment: So, technically I only need to call `db.end()` once each time I use a query inside my main function right? Because then, it add's a db.end que and once all the other queries are finished, it ends it, correct?

Comment: You call `end` once for your connection and not for your query. As soon as you know that you added the last query to the queue of your connection then you can call `.end` on that connection, and after all queries are executed the connection is closed.

Comment: Oh.. So that db.end() is for the whole mysql connection, not individual queries.... Wow, okay I'm starting to understand now.